# Reading multiple images, process them to one image and feed through model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Is there a way to build following graph in Tensorflow:

1. Load some N images (N can vary for each set) using TF Queues and TF Image Readers.
2. Process these images to get fixed size image and prepare batches.
3. Feed these batches through the CNN model

Some questions/info:

1. I am trying to build data loading part in TF instead of Python functions and feed_dict. I guess, TF Data loading can train the model faster compared to python and feed_dict. Is that right ?
2. Building the graph for small N (N<5) is easy. Define exclusive nodes for each image in N and process on them. (working)
3. Can I use TF "while_loop" to build such functionality to read N images ??
4. Does Keras supports such functionality ?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I just did this last week! It was awesome, I learned a ton about tensorflow using things like `tf.map_fn`, and `tf.cond`. And it worked.

This week I just refactored my code to eliminate it all, because it was a bad idea.

Issues I ran into:

1. Doing preprocessing in tensorflow is messy to debug. Doing proper TDD will definitely benefit you here, but still not going to be particularly pretty or easy to debug.
2. You *should* be offloading the preprocessing to the CPU and leaving the GPU (assuming you're using one) to do training. A better approach is to just have a queue and load it from a thread/class that's dedicated to your preprocessing task. And doing the work in numpy/scikit/scikit-image is going to be easier to configure and test.
3. I thought I was so smart, corralling all my code into a single model. But the complexity of the preprocessing meant my model was really hard to iterate on, it got to be rigid code quickly - example is when I added my test set evaluation in, the preprocessing requirement was slightly different. Suddenly I had to add large sections of conditional code to my model and it got ugly quick.

That being said, my preprocessing steps were maybe more complex than yours. If you're sticking to simple things where you can just apply some of the simple image preprocessing steps it might still be easier for you to go this approach.

To answer your questions specifically:

1. Queues won't give any benefit over feed_dict that I know of. You still have a problem of moving data from a TF queue on the CPU to the GPU memory each iteration same as feed_dict does, watch this thread if you care about that topic, GPU queues are coming: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7679
2. You should just `dequeue_many` from the queue, process them as a batch. If you need to do something to each individual image just use `tf.map_fn` which will remove the first dimension and pass individual 3D images to your specified function. But heed my warning above when you go this route - you'll probably be happier just doing this in a separate thread.
3. Already answered in #2, use `tf.map_fn` to iterate over multiple images in a batch. it's pretty easy to use actually.
4. I don't know Keras.

Comment: Hi @DavidParks, thanks a lot for your reply.  1. Based on your suggestions, I would do it in python thread and use feed_dict. 2. My use case is simple I guess, I am not doing much pre-processing (concat, subtract). I will give it a try using tf.map_fn and see how that goes.